Object tracking using MMtrack from detected masks and bounding boxes from MMdetection
I am working with a custom image dataset and instance segmentations generated using Mask R-CNN from MMDetection. I followed your configuration and data conversion instructions but encountered an error.
Custom Dataset Directory Structure:
Workspace\
----Dataset\
--------img1.png
--------img2.png
--------annotations\half-val_detections.pkl

I transformed the MMDetection output into a dictionary as follows:
{
    "image1_name": [MMDetection output as dict],
    "image2_name": [MMDetection output as dict],
    ...
}

Configuration:
_base_ = ['./deepsort_faster-rcnn_fpn_4e_mot17-private-half.py']
data_root = 'workspace/Dataset/'
img_norm_cfg = dict(
    mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53], std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375], to_rgb=True)
test_pipeline = [
    dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
    dict(type='LoadDetections'),
    dict(
        type='MultiScaleFlipAug',
        img_scale=(1088, 1088),
        flip=False,
        transforms=[
            dict(type='Resize', keep_ratio=True),
            dict(type='RandomFlip'),
            dict(type='Normalize', **img_norm_cfg),
            dict(type='Pad', size_divisor=32),
            dict(type='ImageToTensor', keys=['img']),
            dict(type='VideoCollect', keys=['img', 'public_bboxes'])
        ])
]
data = dict(
    val=dict(
        detection_file=data_root + 'annotations/half-val_detections.pkl',
        pipeline=test_pipeline),
    test=dict(
        detection_file=data_root + 'annotations/half-val_detections.pkl',
        pipeline=test_pipeline))

Error Traceback:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "workspace\lib\mmtracking\tools\test.py", line 236, in <module>
    main()
  File "workspace\lib\mmtracking\tools\test.py", line 151, in main
    dataset = build_dataset(cfg.data.test)
  File "workspace\.venv_2\lib\site-packages\mmdet\datasets\builder.py", line 82, in build_dataset
    dataset = build_from_cfg(cfg, DATASETS, default_args)
  File "workspace\.venv_2\lib\site-packages\mmcv\utils\registry.py", line 72, in build_from_cfg
    raise type(e)(f'{obj_cls.__name__}: {e}')
FileNotFoundError: MOTChallengeDataset: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/MOT17/annotations/half-val_cocoformat.json'

I would appreciate your guidance on what might be going wrong here.
I have tried to update the base/datasets/mot_challange.py but that didn't make any change.
